# How to get the list of US time zones only?

Tags: python-2.7, pytz

Can anyone tell me how to get the list of "US" timezones only?I know pytz is a module which gives all time zones in the world. Is there is any way which I can get only the list of time zones from 6 US time zones(Central, Pacific, Eastern, Hawaii, Alaska..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Timezones commonly in use in United States](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#country-information):

```
import pytz

tznames = pytz.country_timezones['us']
```